# Where can I learn how to build a blockchain from scratch?

Tags: blockchain, python, database

I am a newby programmer, I am learning python and objective C and I want to learn how to build a blockchain from the beginning. Are there any resources that could help me.

Answer (score 4):

There was a recent presentation by Portia Burton going over some of the basic steps in creating your own custom blockchain based on Ethereum, however it is in Node not Python as you are requesting.

It's not incredibly detailed, but still it could be useful: https://youtu.be/QWHjp_nzxaY?t=14m11s

There's also this guide on bitcointalk using C++ and the litecoin source code. https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=225690.0

Comment: Am I correct to assume that I can copy Ethereum's source code, modify it to create my own blockchain and sell my new currency, without any problems provided that I follow GPL?